# Using Fancybox with jquery-validate - confirmation box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, fancybox-3

I am really struggling with this.

What I am trying to do for my employer is submit a validated form, the issue is that based on submitted fields a pop-up form (using fancybox version 3 - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) the conditions are that when the location is Scotland and the finalcial amount is over £4,550 (option 2 on the second select box).

I run the validate using `$(this).validate ()` (as there is multiple forms on the page). Then I want to control the `submitHandler` and based on the condition run a fancybox as a `confirmation` so that when the button that appears in the `fb.box` is clicked then the form submit.

I feel like I am not passing some variable or missing something important. I know there are some other ways to maybe achieve this, but due to the styling options available using fancybox this is the prefered method, please help, I have been racking my brain for 2 days trying to do this.

My last resort is to grab and pass the variables from the valiated form into the fancybox and then submit from the box (not ideal, but may be the only way). If you want to view the form please visit:

https://ivapractice.co.uk

```
  $('form').each(function() {  
$(this).validate({
  rules:{
    location:"required",
    debtAmount:"required",
    incomeStatus:"required",
    livingStatus:"required",
    assets:"required",
    fullname:{
      required:true,
      minlength:3
    },
    phonenumber:{
      required:true,
      minlength:11,
      maxlength:11
    },
    email:{
      required:true,
      emailvalidate:true
    },
    gridCheck:"required"
  },
  messages:{
    location:"Please select what region you live in",
    debtAmount:"Please select your approximate debt level",
    incomeStatus:"How do you recieve your income",
    livingStatus:"What's your current living status",
    assets:"Please select an option",
    fullname:"Please enter you full name",
    phonenumber:"Please enter a valid phone number",
    email:"Please enter a valid e-mail address",
    gridCheck:"We require your consent to submit your enquiry"
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // some other code
    // maybe disabling submit button
    // then
    var location = $('[name=location]').val();
    var debtAmount = $('[name=debtAmount]').val();
    var incomeStatus = $('[name=incomeStatus]').val();
    var livingStatus = $('[name=livingStatus]').val();
    var assets = $('[name=assets]').val();
    if(location == 'Scotland'){
      $.fancybox.open({
        src  : 
        '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col"><h1 class="text-center">Thanks for you Enquiry</h1></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col text-center><p>Based on the information you have submitted, an IVA may not be suiteable.</p><p>There are many ways in which we can still help and we work with a panel of debt advice companies that could stilll help.</p><p>Your data is important to us and we just want to maek sure you are happy for you to refer you detaisl for a more suitable soluiotion.<p></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><button data-value="0" data-fancybox-close class="btn">I need a bit more time</button></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><button data-value="1" data-fancybox-close class="btn">Sure that is ok</button></div></div></div>',
        type : 'inline',
        opts : {
          afterLoad: function( instance, current, e) {
            var button = e ? e.target || e.currentTarget : null;
            var value  = button ? $(button).data('value') : 0;
            if(value == 1){
              alert():
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      //$(form).submit();
    }
  }
});
}
```

Comment: can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah I shall get one done in an hour

Comment: Can you do ajax post there? Otherwise, there will be a "too much recursion" error if you try to post by calling `$(form).submit();`

Comment: Please better explain the actual problem you want solved.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys
JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Callistusa/p8Lc42go/
essentaill when the submit button on the form clicked

if the field location is Sotland and the field debtAmount is not equal to the first selectable option, then after check if the subitted fields livingStatus does not equal homeowner and then the other two slected fieds income status equals benefits  and assets does not equal yes then display a popup that shows a statement for GDPR that we are going to refer the details elsewhere.

Comment: i have already set-up the page https://ivapractice.co.uk to recieve the $_Post[] quereis and then process the the page so thats all done

essentiall i wanted to used the submithandle on the jquery-validte to display th pop-up which on the site it is doing, but i need to link the call back from the click  of the button on the fancybox back to run submit if the button "sure that is ok" is clicked

Comment: @user6838959 is it possting to use $ajax() and post the data, need the navigation to the next page with the data so i defot thought it would be at least post, but struggling with how to do the redirect

Comment: Just a thought, do you think if would better to use the onSubmit=function(); and then create a function with the validations i need

Comment: 1) Could you ask more specific question? 2) There is no event (as third argument) passed for `afterLoad` callback, only `beforeClose` event has that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

1. I have added a hidden field to identify whether the user is clicked the "sure that is ok".

`<input type="hidden" value="0" name="is_validated" id="is_validated">`

2. I have updated the `submitHandler` like below.

   ```
   submitHandler: function(form) { 

   // some other code
   // maybe disabling submit button
   // then
   var location = $('[name=location]').val();
   var debtAmount = $('[name=debtAmount]').val();
   var incomeStatus = $('[name=incomeStatus]').val();
   var livingStatus = $('[name=livingStatus]').val();
   var assets = $('[name=assets]').val();
   if(location == 'Scotland' && $('#is_validated').val() != '1'){ // MODIFIED
     $.fancybox.open({
       src  : 
       '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col"><h1 class="text-center">Thanks for you Enquiry</h1></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col text-center><p>Based on the information you have submitted, an IVA may not be suiteable.</p><p>There are many ways in which we can still help and we work with a panel of debt advice companies that could stilll help.</p><p>Your data is important to us and we just want to maek sure you are happy for you to refer you detaisl for a more suitable soluiotion.<p></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><button data-value="0" class="btn data-fancybox-click">I need a bit more time</button></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><button data-value="1" class="btn data-fancybox-click">Sure that is ok</button></div></div></div>', // MODIFIED
       type : 'inline',
       opts : {
         afterLoad: function( instance, current, e) {  // MODIFIED THIS FUNCTION
           $('body').find('.data-fancybox-click').off('click').on('click', function(e){
            var value = $(this).data("value");
            if(value == 1){
               $('#is_validated').val('1');
               $('#landingform button[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
               $.fancybox.close();

             }else{
               $.fancybox.close();
               $('#is_validated').val('0');
             }
           });
         }
       }
     })
   }
   else {
     $(form).submit();
   }
   }
   ```

Removed the attribute `data-fancybox-close` from both buttons in the fancy box and added class `data-fancybox-click`, then added a click event to this buttons and changed the value of  `is_validated` accordingly. If user clicked the button `Sure that is ok` then set `is_validated` value to `1` and trigger the form submit click again.

The fancy box will only displayed if `(location == 'Scotland' && $('#is_validated').val() != '1')`

Comment: thanks for taking you valuabel time to look at this for me, for some reason the fancybox box is not appearing when i run it have uploaded the amendeds to https://ivapractice.co.uk (landing page form - 1st one)

Comment: Seems that multiple elements with same id and name is exists. Please make it unique and check.

Comment: I have normally made the name and  if the same value, is that wrong, just normally made targeting easier, do you think this is causing the conflict

Comment: So i have made all the inputs id's and names different, also as there are two forms  on the page, i have checked that too, so there cannot be and id conflicts the names on the inputs i have kept the same so that on input they could be submited and caught by my PHP mehtod on the next page when.

Sadly the fancy box diden't run thaat time either, updated code is on the same url

Comment: I figured this out the issue is that JQuery Validate runs regardless document ready. So all that I need to do was add an onclick function in addition to the JQuery Validate to run my script
I will post a fiddle in a day or so as an answer, had to take some time to read through the docs for JQuery Validate.